# Johnson's algorithm negative edges - distances matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

The resulting matrix = a matrix on which mat[i][j] is the shortest path with vertex i as source and vertex j as destination.

I have written my own implementation of Johnson's algorithm and I was wondering how does it handle negative edges? In the end, the matrix of distances that I obtain is not the same as the one I get from running Floyd-Warshall. This is obvious as we reweight the graph. Does that mean that Johnson's algorithm does not help us find the cost of the shortest path, but only which of the paths is the shortest one? Also, if there is a path between vertex A and vertex B of cost 0 in the resulting matrix and another one between vertex A and vertex C of cost 0, does that mean that B and C are equally far from A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johnson's algorithm should indeed give back the same paths as what you'd get back with Floyd-Warshall - if you aren't seeing this, it likely means that there's a bug in your implementation somewhere.

You are correct that Johnson's algorithm does reweight the edges of the graph, but it does so in a rather clever way. Specifically, in the new graph, while the *cost* of each path may be different in the new graph than in the original graph, the *relative costs* of paths in the new graph are the same as in the original graph. In that sense, whatever paths come back as the shortest path in the new graph are necessarily going to also be shortest paths from your original graph. The *costs* of those paths in the new graph aren't going to match your original graph, though, and so as a postprocessing step in Johnson's algorithm you're supposed to tweak the costs produced to invert the effect of changing the weights.

Without seeing the code you're running it's hard to say what specifically went wrong, though. You may get more luck posting a follow-up question with some specific code, the specific test case you're running, the specific outputs you're getting, and why you believe they're incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that there was another step in Johnson's algorithm that I forgot to make.